# #GRUB No Windows 10 loading option

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

After re-installing Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop (Lenovo G575) there are no win10 loading option in grub boot menu. There are some info i got:

Boot Info Script cfd9efe + Boot-Repair extra info      [Boot-Info 26Apr2016]

============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

=> Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    for (,msdos6)/boot/grub. It also embeds following components:

```
modules
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
fshelp ext2 part_msdos biosdisk
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       Extended Partition
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info:
```

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       swap
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info:
```

sda6: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       ext4
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info: 
Operating System:  Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab 
                   /boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img
```

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       ntfs
Boot sector type:  Windows 7/2008: NTFS
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  
Boot files:        /bootmgr /Windows/System32/winload.exe
```

*
=================== Suggested repair
The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would purge (in order to) and reinstall the grub2 of sda6 into the MBR of sda.
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s   fix-windows-boot

=================== Final advice in case of suggested repair

The boot files of [The OS now in use - Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS] are far from the start of the disk. Your BIOS may not detect them. You may want to retry after creating a /boot partition (EXT4, >200MB, start of the disk). This can be performed via tools such as gParted. Then select this partition via the [Separate /boot partition:] option of [Boot Repair]. (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition)

*

I dont know what to do now. Help please.

Comment: Did you run `sudo update-grub` ? Turn off Windows 10 fast start up if on. You would have to install Windows boot loader to MBR, boot Windows and turn off fast start, then reinstall grub. Grub only boots working Windows which also means not hibernated. How to restore the Ubuntu/XP/Vista/7/8/10 BIOS bootloader 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader & 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Fixing_a_Broken_System & http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: Post output of `lsblk` and `blkid` please. Also, try running `sudo update-grub` to see if that fixes anything.